# awus306nhr won't connect on dell inspiron with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I just installed ubunutu 14.04 on a new dell inspiron. I need AWUS306NHR in order to get my wifi network at home. The usb network card appears in the network manager but cannot connect whereas builtin wifi can.

I tried

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo reboot
```

as suggested in another forum with no results.

here are the results of the requested command lines:

```
miriam@miriam:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
miriam@miriam:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:920b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:817f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188RU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

any help please?

After some research I found this:

http://en.data-alliance.net/alfa-awus036h-power-problem-fix-realtek-rtl8187l-chipset/

Could this be a solution?

And how can I verify it before buying extra material?

thanks.

gilles

Comment: Is the behavior improved if you blacklist the driver for the internal wifi? What have you done to troubleshoot why the internal won't connect at home? Please edit your question to add the result of these commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `lsusb` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: i found how to edit the blacklist file but i'm not sure what would be the name of the internal wifi to blacklist..?

Comment: The command I suggested shows us: `iwlwifi` Frankly, I'd rather troubleshoot the internal!

Comment: i blacklisted iwlwifi but did not get any better results with it switched off. the internal does not connect at home because signal is too weak. i therefore use the usb one with an antenna to get better signal (and it does work with this same usb card on my older computer in the same location). now if i get the laptop closer to the wifi box, the internal does work but the usb still does not, even if it does get a better signal. any other suggestion?

Comment: I will propose a solution for the USB and then I suggest you start a new question for the internal and we'll work on it together. My own *iwlwifi* device, from which I'm answering this post, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update the driver to the even newer *rtlwif-new*. From a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: ran the requested command lines with succes and reboot, but it did not have any effect. The card finds the network, asks for wifi pasword but then cannot connect. Again it works fine if i plug it on my other computer with ubuntu as well intalled...???

Comment: May we see the wireless script as described here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14440038/

Comment: Note that these results were obtained with the internal connected and the usb disconnected.

Comment: I thought we were working on the USB here and the internal on its own new question. If these results are for the internal, they belong to your separate question.

Comment: I mean to work on the usb. But if i disonnect the internal and get the usb "try" to connect i get the following result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14448993/  Am I doing something wrong in running the code you asked me to?

Comment: You can't download the script without an internet connection. However, since you have already run it, you have a copy of the script already. Just run (execute) it again with the internal disabled, which will overwrite your previous examples. Paste it as above.

Comment: ok. is this better then? http://paste.ubuntu.com/14456896/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Ok. I really doubt router is an issue as i can connect with the same card on another computer. However i am sure your advices do optimise performance.  Have you seen the edit on my main post for a possible solution? Do you have any clues on the issue (although I am conscious this would then not be an ubuntu issue but a hardware issue)? thanks for your help...

Comment: Are you referring to the link about an rtl8187L fix? I am quite confident that it has no relevance to your rtl8192cu.

Comment: ok then, i will forget this solution. I cannot change router settings as it's my friend's (my neighbour's) router. And actually the usb cannot connect to ANY router when plugged in the new dell laptop. Any further suggestions?